# collect a synchronized arraylist from streams in java 8

Tags: java, arraylist, synchronization, thread-safety, java-8

```
List<String> result = map.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                     .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                     .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

The above code will create a ArrayList which is not thread safe. So how can be make it thread safe.

Comment: Why don't you just use map.values().stream()?

Comment: Also, is your map thread safe at all?

Comment: Please note that you need the thread-safe collection only if you want to perform structural modifications on it afterwards. If you want to use it as read-only, `ArrayList` will work fine. Also you don't need a thread-safe collection even if you want to run this stream operation in parallel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want a synchronized collection, you can just change your collector to provide the implementation you want, for example:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<> ()));
```

Or if you prefer a concurrent collection:

```
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(CopyOnWriteArrayList::new));
```

In the latter case, it may be more efficient to use the copy constructor to avoid unnecessary copies of the underlying array.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly better is to move the wrapping into the Collector:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
   .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
   .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), 
                              Collections::synchronizedList))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a synchronized proxy over it after you create it

```
Collections.synchronizedList(map.entrySet()
                 .stream()
                     .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                     .flatMap(x -> x.stream())
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
```